# Книга была без картинок. Какой здесь вид сказуемого?

Tags: синтаксис

Можно ли предложение  **Книга была без картинок** рассматривать как СИС? Мне кажется, здесь ПГС. Однако педагог утверждает, что здесь именно СИС. Задание из 3 класса. Вообще в 3 классе проходят СИС?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Книга была без картинок.* Сказуемое ***была без картинок*** составное именное, глагол-связка быть + имя существительное. Важно не то, что книга была, а важно то, что она без картинок. Ср.:*Книга без картинок.*

Comment: Екатерина, а в  3 классе изучают СИС?

Comment: А если "Он был без дома" . Какое здесь сказуемое?

Comment: Это тоже СИС, обозначен признак, сравнить: он был бездомным.

Answer (score 2):

Это точно СИС, другие примеры: Письмо было от брата. Квартира была без мебели.

Вообще говоря, составное сказуемое включает две части: предикативную (грамматическую) и семантическую (обозначение конкретного признака). В СГС признак процессуальный (действие), а в СИС признак непроцессуальный (качество).

Comment: Лексическое значение глагола "быть" -  "существовать, быть в наличии, иметься".  Так же почему же это значение не подходит под мой пример?

Comment: Да, Екатерина правильно говорит: в предложении утверждается не наличие книги, а указывается ее признак.

Comment: А вот пример с простым сказуемым: Всё это было очень давно.  Здесь предложение распространено обстоятельством времени.

Comment: Sibylla, у вас в ответе ошибка про СГС? Или вы действительно имели это сказуемое? Просто речь идет о ПГС и о СИС. Поэтому спрашиваю.

Comment: В вашем примере речь идет, конечно,  о ПГС и СИС. В ответе я просто даю общую характеристику СОСТАВНОГО сказуемого (СГС и СИС), как бы противопоставляя их ПРОСТОМУ сказуемому, в котором грамматическая и семантическая часть выражены одним глаголом.

Comment: Ясно...........

Comment: *А вот пример с простым сказуемым: Всё это было очень давно.* - а вот тут-то как раз можно поспорить. Наречие может выступать в роли именной части сказуемого, тут, думаю, выбор зависит от понимания. Если в значении типа "было давно и неправда" - то не сказал бы, что так однозначно простое сказуемое. Если же акцент на "было" - то согласен, на СИС не тянет.